# .htaccess Remove .aspx ending on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

old site uses `\index.aspx` or `\service-type.aspx`

New site uses `\` or `\service-type`

which is now wordpress

I tried many syntax posted on SO doesn't seem to redirect at all.. Not sure what my mistake is.

htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.aspx [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Have tried other SO posted solutions but always ends up on 404 for wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to remove `.aspx` from old links. Have your .htaccess like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.aspx[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Hmm How to remove the `/index` at the end? since `.aspx` is now removed.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.aspx[\s?] [NC]` will redirect `/index.aspx` to `/`

Comment: works on root `example.com/index.aspx` when `/testing/index.aspx` is entered result returned `/testing/index`

Comment: Working for 2nd Level now Thanks!

Comment: Obviously this is resolved, but for future reference. You should avoid manually editing anything between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`. Because your changes will be lost if you ever edit Settings > Permalinks.